# Гем devise + omniauth vkontakte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Всем привет. У меня установлен гем devise, я хочу, чтобы после авторизации по гему devise, можно было авторизироваться через vk. Помогите, пожалуйста, в реализации, особенно с роутингом. Скайп приветствуется. Спасибо большое заранее!

Comment: Так а что уже пробовали? `omniauth-vkontakte` поставили?

Comment: @D-side гем добавил, сделал всё как в http://habrahabr.ru/post/142128/ до момента, где включают сервер. У меня постоянные ошибки с роутингом, мол, нет таких роутов и ещё выбивает ошибки на 
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :nickname, :provider, :url, :username

Comment: Там, если что, используются рельсы 3.2.3, когда актуальная 4.2, а на пороге 5.0. Пошаговым руководствам к старым версиям следовать опасно. Да и в целом пошаговые руководства без объяснений "почему", и "что это означает" (коей является и эта статья на Хабре) для новичков, ИМХО, даже вредны. У меня с собеседований завалялся [пример для фейсбука](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server), там тоже решительно никаких объяснений, "как", зато работоспособно (правда, оно является для OAuth2 одновременно и провайдером, и клиентом). Разбирался пару дней. Подготовлю объяснения, как будет время.

Comment: @D-side спасибо большое. С вами можно как-то связаться или добавить в Вас друзья в какой-то сети, чтобы можно было спрашивать в более удобной форме для переписки?

Comment: У меня на сайте есть контакты, но предпочтительнее чат-комната здесь, чтобы могли вклиниться и другие участники сообщества.

Comment: @D-side понял. Буду ждать Ваши объяснения и попутно искать информацию в интернете

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Собственно, всё примерно так же, как и с Facebook, по [примеру с вики Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Внутри это работает достаточно просто:

1. Вы переходите по ссылке от вашего сайта, он перенаправляет на ВК.
2. ВК спрашивает разрешения у вас, после чего перенаправляет вас обратно на сайт, добавив в ссылку код доступа.
3. Сайт использует код доступа, чтобы получить у провайдера запрашиваемые данные.

В центре всего: пользователь разрешает сайту доступ к его информации. А эта информация даёт OmniAuth пару id-провайдер, достаточную для аутентификации.

Чтобы это всё обеспечить, вам нужно (на свежем проекте):

1. Добавить `devise` и `omniauth-vkontakte` в `Gemfile`, установить.
2. Установить Devise: `rails g devise:install` и отредактировать созданный `devise.rb`:

   - На этом этапе вам нужно будет ввести данные о [своём приложении](https://vk.com/dev), которое служит "представительством" вашего сайта в ВК. Вам потребуются "ID приложения" и "защищённый ключ". Ближе к низу `devise.rb` расположен пример указания провайдера OmniAuth для `github`: вам нужно написать аналогичную строчку для `vkontakte`.
   - Имейте в виду, что ключ и ID приложения публиковать не стоит, ВК считает, что их знаете только вы, поэтому если будете публиковать исходники, подтягивайте эти данные извне с помощью решений вроде `figaro` или `config`, как я это сделал [тут](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/config/initializers/devise.rb#L239).
3. Создайте модель `User` и добавьте туда поля `provider` и `uid`, плюс внесите изменения в сам файл модели:

   - `rails g devise User uid provider` сделает нужную миграцию, но стоит перепроверить её на предмет ненужных вам полей
   - Добавьте в модель в аргументы вызова `devise` вот эти: `:omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:vkontakte]`
4. Почти всё! Осталось сделать точку возврата из ВК на сайт, которая примет код доступа и достанет с его помощью нужные данные.

   - Создайте новый контроллер, который наследуется от `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`
   - Сделайте там метод `vkontakte`
   - Зайдите в маршруты (`routes.rb`) и укажите там этот контроллер:

     ```
     devise_for :users, # <- внимание, запятая, вызов ещё не кончился
       controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
       # У меня контроллер Users::OmniauthCallbacksController
     ```

**Готово!** Да, серьёзно. Правда, в таком виде практической пользы от этого никакой, но у вас есть всё, что надо:

- В методе `vkontakte`, добавленном выше, доступна вся информация, пришедшая от ВК, в `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` -- вы, вероятно, захотите [делать/находить по этой информации пользователя](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb#L3) и [залогиниваться за него](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb#L5) (а вы можете быть уверены, что эта информация корректна).
- Весь процесс со стороны пользователя инициируется переходом по адресу, генерируемому хелпером `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:vkontakte)`, который разумно [запаковать в ссылку](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/app/views/home/index.html.slim#L14) и показывать только гостям.

Далее стоит заняться некоторой уборкой (изолировать данные приложения от исходного кода, например) и "обработкой провалов" (что если пользователь [откажется давать данные?](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb#L17)).

Вот набросанный наспех [пример на гитхабе](https://github.com/D-side/auth-vk). [Метод `vkontakte`](https://github.com/D-side/auth-vk/blob/master/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb#L2) в нём не делает ничего, кроме вызова сессии отладчика, позволяя осмотреть контекст, в котором оказалась программа. Этого, в целом, достаточно, чтобы убедиться в работоспособности.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее за такой подробное руководство! Буду пробовать и я уверен, что будут вопросы возникать в процессе. Не прощаюсь :)

Comment: Где брать ID приложения и защищённый ключ?

Comment: @basania [в панели управления для разработчиков](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) в ВК.

Comment: Спасибо. Если у меня есть уже миграция похожая, но не такая, какая мне нужна и от той миграции поля попали в schema.rb. Как убрать эти поля из schema.rb без последствий?

Comment: @basania schema.rb всего лишь слепок состояния БД и необязательно отражает последствия применения всех миграций (хотя по-хорошему, должен). В миграции можно делать [довольно много всего](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html).

Comment: понял, спасибо. Ещё такой вопрос: при создании нового приложение в ВК выбирать веб-сайт? Если я залью на heroku сайт, я могу его обновлять там?

Comment: @basania да, и не знаю, с чего бы это повлияло на Heroku -- лишь бы домен был верный.

Comment: я имею в виду, что я залью сайт на хостинг и когда я обновлю код на локальном сервере, как его обновить сразу же и на Heroku? Я в продакшн ни разу не работал

Comment: @basania Heroku использует код из своего git-репозитория для запуска. Как только вы делаете `git push`, он пробует собрать "упаковку" с приложением и запустить его, прогресс виден прямо в выводе команды `git push` -- если по каким-то причинам сборка не удалась, Heroku не примет изменений. Больше на базовые вопросы отвечать не буду, пройдите уже [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning) =)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответы и терпение. Буду разбираться :)

Comment: Добрый вечер. Я уже второй день не могу задеплоить приложение на heroku из-за sqlite3. Перерыл кучу форумов, менял много чего и всё равно проблема остаётся. Я не могу перейти с sqlite на postgresql. Если я создам репозиторий на github, вы сможете, пожалуйста, посмотреть и помочь? Спасибо.

Comment: Вам **придётся** уйти с SQLite3, поскольку Heroku предоставляет базы данных в виде аддонов (только MySQL или PostgreSQL из реляционных). Поскольку рельсовый ActiveRecord в чистом виде подстраивается под разные БД, можете локально использовать SQLite, а удалённо PostgreSQL. Опять же, смотрите Rails Tutorial. Да и в целом делать в многопользовательском приложении SQLite -- отвратительная идея :)

Comment: Я понимаю и поэтому хочу перейти с SQLite на PostgreSQL. Но у меня не получается. Я пробовал туториал. У меня он заработал на моём старом приложении, но на этом, на котором работаю в данный момент, это не работает. Я понятия не имею почему. Я убрал из Gemfile.rb sqlite, из Gemlock тоже убрал и зависимости тоже.В database.yml поставил на development, test, production postresql (в соответствии с Gemfile) и всё равно ошибка.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29317/discussion-between-d-side-and-basania).